# Get all occurrences of the search pattern

Tags: regex, sed, replace

I try to get all occurrences of a pattern from a file, but currently I fail if there is more than one occurrence per line.

Sample line in file:

```
lorem ipsum foo="match1" lorem ipsum foo="match2" lorem ipsum
```

The output I want:

```
match1 match2
```

I tried getting this using sed:

```
sed -ne 's/^.*foo="\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/p'
```

With this expression I only get the first occurence, but I don't know how to make it better.

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep` instead of `sed`.

```
grep -o -P '(?<=foo=")[^"]*'
```

Comment: Be aware that this only works if your `grep` happens to have been compiled with support for the `-P` (Perl syntax) option.  Vanilla `grep` doesn't support lookbehind or any of the other whizbang features found in Perl and the Perl-derived regex flavors.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ s="lorem ipsum foo="match1" lorem ipsum foo="match2" lorem ipsum"
$ echo $s|tr "[ \t]" "\n"|awk -F"=" '$1=="foo"{print $2}'
match1
match2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to show you that you probably don't want to use `sed`. It works and it's fairly robust, but it may fail on some corner cases:

```
sed -n 's/\(foo="[^"]*\)/\n\1\n/g;s/[^\n]*\n*foo="//g;s/\n"[^n]*$//p' file
```